# Why the obj value is null in asp web API2 controller when the angular http.post has the correct value

Tags: c#, angular, angular7

I am working on a small project to learn Angular7 with ASP WebAPI2. When I post using the http.post() the ASP web API controller doesn't receive any value and the obj is set to null.

I have tried to implement similar codes in other parts of the application and working ok.

My WebAPI looks like this -

```
        [Route("api/rota/InsertRota")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage InsertRota(Models.HelpdeskStaffRota paraStaffRota)
        {
            try
            {
                string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpdeskStaffRota"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("RotaInsert", conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RotaDate", paraStaffRota.RotaDate));
                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RotaMorning", paraStaffRota.RotaMorning));
                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RotaLunch", paraStaffRota.RotaLunch));
                    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RotaLate", paraStaffRota.RotaLate));
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                List<Models.HelpdeskStaffRota> items = GetItems();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther, e.Message); }
        }
```

and the asp model -

```
    public class HelpdeskStaffRota
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a date")]
        public DateTime RotaDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Staff for Morning")]
        public string RotaMorning { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Staff for Lunch")]
        public string RotaLunch { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Staff for Late")]
        public string RotaLate { get; set; }

        public string RotaDateString {
            get
            {
                return this.RotaDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            }
            set
            {
                this.RotaDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }


        }


    }
```

And the Angular service -

```
  addRota(rota: Rota) {
    const addRotaURL = `${this.baseURL}api/rota/InsertRota`;
    return this.http.post(addRotaURL, rota);
  }
```

and the angluar rota class -

```
export class Rota {
    Id: number;
    RotaDate: Date;
    RotaMorning: string;
    RotaLunch: string;
    RotaLate: string;
}
```

If I go in debug mode, I can see the angular code does have an object value set and i can see it hits the break points inside the controller however the value for paraStaffRota is null. My expectation is paraStaffRota(web api controller)  =  rota (posted from angular).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be a datetime issue, try to use date RotaDate as string both sides and then see the result

Comment: @sharmav1 - you are right, It's the date type is causing the issue. It seems to be working ok with string. Cheers

Comment: I have tried to convert the date to string like that `this.selectedRota.RotaDate = this.modelRotaDate.getFullYear() + '-' + this.modelRotaDate.getMonth() + '-' + this.modelRotaDate.getDate();` however shows error in run-time - "ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getFullYear'"

Comment: I have also tried to use this `formatDate(this.modelRotaDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en-us')`, same result shows error in run-time.

Comment: please share your answer with others, so that others can also benefit from it. Cheers

Comment: hi @sharmav1, sorry i don't have an answer just yet. i have tried using a string like you have suggested i.e - `this.selectedRota.RotaDate = '2019-05-23'` and this seems to work ok. however i am still looking to have it done in runtime. i have mentioned couple of issues in my previous comments. cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who are looking for a better way of doing this-

I think using a custom Date Adapter would be a better and cleaner way of doing this. I have done the below.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DateStringService {

    constructor() { }

    fromModel(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        let segments = value.split('-');
        let dateObj = {
            year: Number(segments[0]),
            month: Number(segments[1]),
            day: Number(segments[2])
        };

        return dateObj;
    }

    toModel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        if (!date) {
            return;
        }

        return `${date.year}-${date.month}-${date.day}`;
    }
}
```

And then used it in app.module.ts-

```
    providers: [
        { provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: DateStringService }
    ],
```

That’s it. Off you go! You don’t need to change anything anywhere else. Angular will take it from here. It’s working for me and I find this approach better and cleaner than my previous approach. Hope that helps. If you come across a better solution, please share it here.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question (you are telling ng-bootstrap date picker to convert dates to/from string). You would be better of doing the conversion before the POST. If you do it like this, you will get strings all over the place which will only make it harder for you to do actual date operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could add [FromBody] to your parameter

```
public HttpResponseMessage InsertRota([FromBody] Models.HelpdeskStaffRota paraStaffRota)
{
 // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@sharmav1 was very rightly suggested to try using String instead of using Date, however i have come across other issues with Date type in angular.

I have found a work around as manipulating the Date type in angular didn't go very well. It's not a great solution and may be worth looking into this with more time in hand. I have created a function that takes a Date Type obj and will return the Date in String i.e. YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
getDateInString(dateObj: Date): string {
    const str: string[] = JSON.stringify(dateObj).replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split(',');
    return str[0].substring(7) + '-' + str[1].substring(8) + '-' + str[2].substring(6);
}
```

Passing a String value to RotaDate to my ASP API seems to convert the String into correct C# DateTime type and is now working ok.

If I come across a better solution, I will post it here.